# Не хватает памяти [php]

Tags: php

Можно ли как-то увеличить? 
В `php.ini` стоит **512**

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 72 bytes)

Comment: да не обращай внимания. главное - получить ответ

Answer (score 4):

Итак, у вас в php.ini стоит значение 512Мб, а скрипт считает, что ему выделено 128Мб.
Возможно, у вас что-то из этого:

1. Вы смотрите/вносите правки не в тот php.ini или в конфигурации какая-то ошибка. Выведите phpinfo() и проверьте.
2. Размер выделяемой памяти уменьшен в настройках веб-сервера. В Апаче, например, это делается вот такой директивой: `php_admin_value memory_limit 128MB`.
3. Установлено ограничение на уровне .htaccess: `php_value memory_limit 128MB`. Помните, что значения .htaccess могут браться из родительских директорий.
4. Где-то в вашем скрипте всё-таки вызывается `ini_set("memory_limit","128M");`.

Answer (score 2):

Увеличить естественно можно, измените **512** на более высокое значение и перезапустите веб-сервер. А лучше попробуйте разобраться с участком кода в котором происходит утечка памяти. Найдите часть скрипта вызов которой вызывает ошибку и приведите его в вопросе.

Comment: я знаю участок этого кода, но без этого не как. Там за 30 сек идет опрос 10 ка серверов. и судя по ошибке 134217728 байт это 128 мегабайт которые выделяет тот же [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) но в скрипте его нет. что может еще ограничить в эти 128 я не могу понять и пришел тут спросить.  мозг мой кипит...

Comment: тогда советую развести как-то опрос. например делать его не одновременно, а в порядке очередности, пока не получен результат от первого опроса не переходить к опросу второго. варианты есть всегда.

Comment: нет, не это я спрашивал.